# I need to get my Java program to start back at the beginning after an invalid input

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I'm currently working on an assignment for school and I am almost done but I just have one large problem I need to fix before I can add the final bit.

I need to create a program that prompts you to enter either 1 or 2, Afterwards it asks you to enter three words/names and saves them into an array.

Then, depending on whether you picked 1 or 2, it prints them in alphabetical order or flips around the lowercase and uppercase letters. I didn't add that part yet because I'm trying to fix a problem related to the very first input.

When you input a number other than 1 or 2, I am instructed to display an error message and ask for input again. I am pretty sure what I need to do is get the entire program to go back to the beginning because copy/pasting the entire program again would be bad, lol

A big problem is probably that I'm using if/else statements with for loops inside when I might need to put the entire thing inside a loop? But I'm not sure what condition I would use to start the loop if I put the entire code in it. I must be missing something here.

With what I have now, it gets stuck saying invalid input even if you put in a 1 or 2.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IsabellaPiantoniLab5 {
   public static void main (String[]args) {

       //Ask for input
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Please choose either a number 1 or number 2.");
       int numChoice = input.nextInt();

       //if choice is 1 or 2
       if (numChoice == 1 || numChoice == 2) {

           System.out.println("Please enter three names: ");
           String nameInput[] = new String[4];

           //input loop
           for (int i= 0; i < nameInput.length; i++) {

           nameInput[i] = input.nextLine();
       }

       System.out.println("Values are:");

       //display values if 1
       if (numChoice == 1) {
           for (int i=1; i<4; i++) {
               System.out.println(nameInput[i]);
           }
       }
       //display values if 2
       else if (numChoice == 2) {
            for (int i=1; i<4; i++) {
                System.out.println(nameInput[i]);
             }
       }
}

//retry if invalid------i restart from the beginning if this happens
else if (numChoice != 1 || numChoice != 2) {

  System.out.println("Invalid value. Please try again.");
  //continue;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of putting all your code in `main()`, try breaking functional bits out into their own methods.  It'll make it a lot easier to (re)invoke code that way.

Comment: You need something like `while (userInput != 1 || 2) { userInput = askForUserInput() }`.

Comment: You wrote "if (numChoice != 1 || numChoice != 2)" but that's always true.  Either numChoice isn't one... or it isn't two.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.exit(0);
```

This will terminate the app, thus you can start it again using command line `( START [your app path])`

Or

```
RunTime.getRuntime().exec(“Your app”);
System.exit(0);
```

**Edit** I misunderstood the question, I thought you wanted to restart the whole app 
After discussing the approach with @csm_dev
It is way either to ask for the user input one more time by emptying the field and showing a message “please enter a valid input” with a clarification message

Comment: Exiting and manually restarting the entire application just because the user made a typo is a terrible way to handle the situation.

Comment: Thus you can take the second approach

Comment: The 2nd approach will not exit the application? It won't require a restart? When you call `System.exit()` you are closing the program which, again, is a terrible solution. Also, please don't use 'smart quotes' in your code.

Comment: It will run another instance of the app and terminate this one

Comment: The question still remains: why would you do this instead of simply using a loop?

Comment: So instead of close and restart, you restart and then close? That is no different. Executing a program multiple times simply because of a typo should not be suggested.

Comment: Tell me how you are going to do this, this piece of information is missing for me

Comment: You just ask the user for input again - simple as that.

Comment: I thought you were talking about restarting the whole app instead of re asking the user for the same input, in that case yes it is much easier and beneficial

Comment: "_When you input a number other than 1 or 2, I am instructed to display an error message and ask for input again_"